# Paypal | AxisFault: 400 Bad Request

Tags: paypal-sandbox, tls1.2, bad-request

We are getting Bad Request while connecting to PayPal sandbox account using classic SOAP APIs.

This started after we have upgraded paypal TLS 1.2 certificates

Request is hit through paypalstubs_v97.jar.

Although same code is working for production account but getting Bad Request from PayPal for staging environment.

Answer (score 0):

TLS 1.2 is not a certificate type, it is a protocol. Perhaps you mean the SHA-256 signed certificates. You may need to review https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/lifecycle/info-security-guidelines/ more carefully

You'll probably need to contact PayPal tech support (MTS) if you're not going to provide any troubleshooting information, such as logging the full bad request response output, including HTTP headers, and also testing verbosely independently of java via e.g. `curl -v -d '...'`, for comparison and reference.  But they would probably also want that type of information to be of help.

---

PayPal's classic SOAP APIs are extremely old, so this is also a good opportunity to consider upgrading to some modern web services.

- Front end:
  https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server
- Back end:
  https://github.com/paypal/Checkout-Java-SDK